# AWS - StepFunctions: How to access artifacts with StepFunctions from previous stage in CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, devops, aws-codepipeline, aws-step-functions

I have the following pipeline:

[AWS - Codepipeline flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z5cQ.png)

I am having trouble linking the output artifacts from the source (GitHub) stage to the input artifacts of the StepFunctions stage.

My goal is for my StepFunctions stage to have access to the last zip file name (on S3 Bucket) that the source stage output to.

I already tried:

1. Define Namespace in the Source stage to use it in the StepFunctions stage.
   link to docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html
2. Read this docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-step-functions.html
3. new case: Stage with Lambda instead StepFunctions, it receives the link to S3 folder and other meta-data from the Source stage while StepFunctions do not.